# What if nginx load balancer crashed or need to update

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as a load balancer, which is fine if one of my server is down the app still running perfectly, I'm wondering what if the requests are too many and nginx goes down... 
Or, if I what to reboot or update the server which nginx is running on, is there any way I can do it without interrupt the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires minimum 2 servers and a DNS service that can route to the healthly server.